# How to solve stack "smashing detected"

Tags: c++

I wrote a very simple c++ program to generate random string. And while execute the following code it gives 'stack smashing detected'.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define SIZE 30
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    string str;
    int len = rand() % SIZE;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        str[i] = (char)((rand() % 26) + 'a');
    //      cout<<str[i];
    }
    cout<<str<<endl<<"..."<<endl<<len<<endl;
}
```

Comment: All containers (including `std::string`) are *empty* by default. Any indexing in them will be out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Change that line to `str.at(i) = (char)((rand() % 26) + 'a');` and the exception thrown will give you a big hint as to the answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initialize your string, it has a size of `0`

```
string str;
```

Therefore any assignment you do is out of bounds here

```
str[i] = ...
```

You need to resize your string after you know the length

```
int len = rand() % SIZE;
str.resize(len);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str[i] = (char)((rand() % 26) + 'a');
```

`str` has not yet allocated any data, so this is undefined behaviour. use `str +=` instead.